# Sort, Search(Filter), Paginate HTML Table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to sort, paginate and search(search based on a column) a HTML table. I was looking at the various JQuery Plugins like [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/index), TableSorter, [Picnet Table Filter](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet_table_filter.html), etc. but I couldn't find any plugin which does all the 3 work (Searching, Sorting and Pagination). I have seen such a table in PHP Yii Framework but they have their own CSS and then I will have to convert my rewrite my whole project with Yii.  DataTable does have a filter option but that will search a value along all the columns. What I want is to search only in one columns. I am not sure whether I will able to that with DataTable or not. Does anybody know is there any JQuery Plugin for this or any other method to do this

Comment: DataTable allows you to apply Searching, Sorting and Pagination. You can even see it on the homepage under Example header... You may also customize it to match your requirements. 
[1]: http://www.datatables.net/index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found this in the demo's of DataTables: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Should have all 3 of your requirements.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot Björn & Andrzej Ośmiałowski. That indeed will solve out my query

Comment: What if i don't want to use datatables??
for large data datatable is too slow.
I have around 300,000 data in the table and datatable takes too much time to load.
So i made a custom pagination and searching for search option 
what should i do?

Comment: @xravn use Datatable server side processing. Which will limit the number of records loaded with pagination. Use Datatable plugin itself don't write your own as it support searching, sorting and other functionality, since it's open source  there are many plugins contributed to it which you may find useful for later implementation and up gradations

Comment: is there something similar but with php?

Answer (score 0):

**JP list** will be the perfect one for your requirement >> https://jplist.com/ .

Those who wants to work around with Divs elements, gallery, other html elements rather than tables , this will be the perfect jQuery plugin for this. This one includes **Pagination, Sorting, Filtering and More**. All in one package. 
***Demos*** : https://jplist.com/demo